# How to add other projects in current project in Gradle?

Tags: interface-builder, gradle

I have two projects ProjA and ProjB, here ProjB is depends on ProjA. So, how to include ProjA in ProjB?
And please let me know in case change in the ProjA build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have two projects, whereas ProjA depends on ProjB.

If you have already set up a gradle build for those, both of them will have a file settings.gradle, which at least defines the project name and build.gradle, where you can specify the dependencies.

Example:
settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'ProjA'
```

build.gradle

```
group = 'mygroup'
version = '1.0'
```

By further adding one of Gradle's publishing plugins (see [Maven publishing](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) or [Ivy publishing](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_ivy.html)), you can configure a publication. A publication in turn contains artifacts, that is the files you want to upload (and usually some repositories).
Example for a minimal Maven publication:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing {
    publications {
        core(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

The maven-publish plugin will add the task `publishToMavenLocal` (among others) to your project which installs the jar somewhere to `~/.gradle/caches/`.

In build.gradle of ProjB you can then define a compile time dependency on ProjA like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'mygroup', name: 'ProjA', version: '1.0')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can u please tell me how to upload project artifact into local repository? Because, after adding "apply plugin: 'maven-publish'" in build.gradle of ProjA, executed "build" command and not able to find out in which location it is added in local machine.

Comment: You need to configure the publishing plugin first. See the updated post for a minimal configuration of the maven-publish plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If your projects are co-located, you could have a multi build project.

Say you have a root folder with these contents:

- some root directory

  - project-a

    - `project-a.gradle`
    - src
  - project-b

    - `project-b.gradle`
    - src
  - `build.gradle`
  - `settings.gradle`

`settings.gradle` contains:

```
include 'project-a', 'project-b'
```

`project-b.gradle` then depends on project A:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':project-a')
}
```

After this, project a will always compile and assemble before project-b and the jar file for project-a jar will be on the classpath when compiling project-b.

Comment: Our projects are not co-located, but ProjB is depending on ProjA in order to compile ProjB. I have tried inlcuding ProjA in settings.gradle and by adding "compile project(':ProjA')" in ProjB. But ProjB is not able to build becoz of dependencies.

Comment: you can't put a dependency on a project that isn't co-located so that will never work. You are stuck with either publishing to a local repository and picking it up through there, or you could compile ProjA and put the jar in a lib folder of ProjectB and then reference it.

    `repositories { flatDir dirs: 'lib' }`

    `dependencies { compile ':projectA_jar_name' //no jar extension just name }`